# Rotate element based on touch event

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, rotation

I'm looking for some guidance and/or examples to create a way to touch an object and rotate it. Let's say we had an image of a circle, I want to be able to touch one point, drag around that circle and manipulate it to spin as my finger moves.

I'm finding plenty of tutorials on rotating:

- http://www.williammalone.com/briefs/how-to-rotate-html5-canvas-around-center/
- http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/html-5-canvas-tutorial-rotation

I just need to get the touch part incorporated.

Anyone done this before or can shed some light?

Answer (score 3):

You could simply map the rotation of the touch to the element's `transform: rotate(Ndeg)` CSS.

Not all touch-enabled browsers provide a `rotate` property on the `event` object, so you can figure out the value with a splash of math.

```
document
.getElementById("some-element")
.addEventListener("touchmove", function(event) {
    var rotation = event.rotation;

    // This isn't a fun browser!
    if ( ! rotation) {
         rotation = Math.atan2(event.touches[0].pageY - event.touches[1].pageY,
               event.touches[0].pageX - event.touches[1].pageX) * 180 / Math.PI;
    }

    // Take into account vendor prefixes, which I haven't done.
    this.style.transform = "rotate(" + rotation + "deg)":
});
```

You will also need to store the previous rotation value and adjust this one based off it if you want the user to be able to rotate it more than once. :)

Comment: I can't find any rotation property in touch event. How to access that?

Answer (score 1):

### Rotate element on mouse/touch drag

Here's a complete example on how to *drag-rotate* an Element:

**Store the start angle**, which is the relative angle at coordinates minus the current angle.
**Rotate by the difference** (delta) of the mousemove XY coordinates angle from center minus the start angle.

```js
const rotate = (EL) => {
  
  let ang = 0; // All angles are expressed in radians
  let angStart = 0;
  let isStart = false;

  const angXY = (ev) => {
    const bcr = EL.getBoundingClientRect();
    const radius = bcr.width / 2;
    const { clientX, clientY } = ev.touches ? ev.touches[0] : ev;
    const y = clientY - bcr.top - radius;  // y from center
    const x = clientX - bcr.left - radius; // x from center
    return Math.atan2(y, x);
  };

  const mousedown = (ev) => {
    isStart = true;
    angStart = angXY(ev) - ang;
  };

  const mousemove = (ev) => {
    if (!isStart) return;
    ev.preventDefault();
    ang = angXY(ev) - angStart;
    EL.style.transform = `rotateZ(${ang}rad)`;
  };

  const mouseup = () => {
    isStart = false; 
  };

  EL.addEventListener("mousedown", mousedown);
  document.addEventListener("mousemove", mousemove);
  document.addEventListener("mouseup", mouseup);
};

document.querySelectorAll(".rotate").forEach(rotate);
```

```css
.rotate {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 180px;
  cursor: ns-resize;
}
```

```html
<img class="rotate" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/1771ce957b38fbb7f9bb01f58b89fd3f?s=328&d=identicon&r=PG" alt="Wheel image">
<img class="rotate" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCWYU.jpg?s=328&g=1" alt="Wheel image">
```

Answer (score 0):

You will want to look at implementing `MouseDown`, `MouseUp`, and `MouseMove` event listeners on your `canvas`, since "touch" interaction with a touch screen is nothing more than a fancy mouse movement.

`MouseDown` and `MouseUp` are useful for finding if the user is dragging across the `canvas` or not. `MouseMove` is where you will need to put the rotation processing logic. The rest is implementation:

```
/* Borrowed from http://www.marceloduende.com/blog/?p=25 */
function addCrossBrowseEventListener(myElement, myEvent, myFunction) {  
    if(myElement.addEventListener){  
        myElement.addEventListener(myEvent, myFunction, false);  
        return true;  
    } else {  
        myElement.attachEvent('on'+myEvent, myFunction);  
        return true;  
}
```

Where `myElement` is the DOM element for your canvas, `myEvent` is the name of the event to add a listener for, and `myFunction` is the name of the function that is tasked with the logic for the event.

Alternatively, you could use jQuery to do most of this, as it has a number of cleaner methods for event handling.

Comment: Thanks Justin—all makes sense, unfortunately I don't have enough experience to make it all work on my own. Do you know of any examples I might be able to reverse engineer? Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure if the OP is wanting mobile events, they say "touch" and not "click", so I'm inclined to think this is for something on a touchscreen device. In which case the events would be "touchstart" and "touchmove"